# Python packet sniff for specific program

Tags: python, packet-sniffers

I was looking for a method to sniff packets being received and sent by a specific program, as I have seen some packet analyzers such as CommView have the ability to do "Packet-to-application mapping".

I want to achieve this in Python, and I don't mind any extra modules that I have to install and am already familiar with the Scapy and socket modules.

I would prefer this to be on Windows, but if that's not possible I could use Ubuntu.

: this is my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pyshark](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark) works with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) and its component [TShark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) on both Windows and Linux. It's a bit immature, but might suit your purposes.

You should install it from the GitHub repository; the PyPI version seems to be missing a fix that causes an error.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and from the looks of the "usage" it has a similar output as Scapy. Thanks a lot. :)